# i need to implement square() by repeated addition. I don't know what I'm doing wrong

Tags: c++

In this program I am trying to implement the square function using repeated addition.
The output I'm am getting is simply twice the value of x (input).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
inline void keep_window_open() { char ch; cin >> ch; }
int square (int x) {
  for (int i = 0; i <= x; ++i) {
    x += x; // adding the value of x to x each time 
    return x;
    }
  }
  int main() 
  {
    int x;
    cout << "Enter a value for x" << endl;
    cin >> x;
    cout << square (x);
  }
```

Comment: Your `return` statement is *inside* your loop, so it will only iterate once. You also have a logical problem since you're reusing `x` as both the delta and the accumulator.

Comment: The loop condition is evaluated in each step, and as you modify `x`  the counter will be wrong, and it will result in an endless loop. You should have a separate variable to store the result.

Comment: `i <= x;` should be `i < x;`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to chage your code to the follwoing one:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= x; ++i) {
    x += x; // adding the value of x to x each time 
}
return x;
```

The reason why your code doesn't work as it should be, was that you had your return element int you `for` loop. Also you have to change you accumulator.

```
int result = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
    result += x; // adding the value of x to the accumulator.
}
return result;
```

Comment: Also the `x += x;` is wrong, results in an endless loop.

Comment: Yeah you are right. I just noticed that. I will point out this also. Thank you.

Comment: And now you just have to incorporate πάντα ῥεῖ 's comment and it will contain all three mistakes of the OP  -- I see you did it meanwhile

Comment: Yeah I already did it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to handle negative input

```
int square (int x) 
{
    unsigned int result = 0;
    unsigned int absolute_x = std::abs(x);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < absolute_x; ++i)
    {
        result += absolute_x;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int square (int x) {
for (int i = 0; i <= x; ++i) {
x += x; // adding the value of x to x each time 
return x;
}
}
```

Your `return x;` is inside your loop so after it increases the value of x the first time it just returns, also you can't say `i <= x` since you'll be changing the value x. So if you want to make your code work you need to put `return x;` at the end of your function and create another int variable to memorize the value of x else you'll end up in infinite loop and your program would crash.

```
int square (int x) {
int j = x;
for (int i = 0; i <= j; ++i) {
x += x; // adding the value of x to x each time 
}
return x;
}
```

That way it will make additions until you have x = x^2 and then it will exit the loop and return the value.

You can also use sqrt(x) from math library for the same result. But note that `return` always acts in the same way as `break;` so it will stop the execution of your loop (and function / program ) when it reaches that point. For instance you could write your code like:

```
while(1){
++i;
if(i>j) return x;
x+=x;
}
```